# Structure compare of two Python scripts on a byte code level

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a teacher, it is sometimes difficult to tell whether an exercise has been completed by a student themselves. For my Python exercises it would be great to check the content of different python scripts - not only the variable, function and class names.
A normal text diff wouldn't work because these names can be easily changed without knowing about coding.

For example, is it possible to compare the structure on a byte code level of the following two scripts?

student_1.py

```
def my_add(a,b):
  return a+b

print(my_add(3,4))
```

student_2.py

```
def Add(x1,x2):
  return x1+x2

print(Add(4,3))
```

***Addendum*** , get bytecode :

```
import dis

source = """
def Add(x1,x2):
  return x1+x2

print(Add(4,3))
"""


a = compile('source' , '<string>' , 'exec')

print(dis.dis(source))
```

output:

```
0           0 RESUME                   0
2           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object Add at 0x7fba144ebdf0, file "<dis>", line 2>)
4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
6 STORE_NAME               0 (Add)
5           8 PUSH_NULL
10 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
12 PUSH_NULL
14 LOAD_NAME                0 (Add)
16 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
18 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
20 PRECALL                  2
24 CALL                     2
34 PRECALL                  1
38 CALL                     1
48 POP_TOP
50 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
52 RETURN_VALUE
Disassembly of <code object Add at 0x7fba144ebdf0, file "<dis>", line 2>:
2           0 RESUME                   0
3           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (x1)
4 LOAD_FAST                1 (x2)
6 BINARY_OP                0 (+)
10 RETURN_VALUE
None
>
```

and

```
import dis

source = """
def my_add(a,b):
  return a+b

print(my_add(3,4))
"""


a = compile('source' , '<string>' , 'exec')

print(dis.dis(source))
```

output:

```
0           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object my_add at 0x7f3ca44ebdf0, file "<dis>", line 2>)
4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (my_add)

  5           8 PUSH_NULL
             10 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
             12 PUSH_NULL
             14 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_add)
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
             20 PRECALL                  2
             24 CALL                     2
             34 PRECALL                  1
             38 CALL                     1
             48 POP_TOP
             50 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             52 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object my_add at 0x7f3ca44ebdf0, file "<dis>", line 2>:
  2           0 RESUME                   0

  3           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 BINARY_OP                0 (+)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly your comparison should result in? What kind of differences are you looking for? Do you want to see if two files are basically the same simply with different variable/function names? The byte code of a Python script still contains the original variable/function names.

Comment: Depending on the assignment, just how different do you think correct solutions *will* be to the same question?

Comment: Yes, that would be the first step to determine whether only the variable names differ or the program structure. The second step could be to identify the difference in the used data structure. If you see the code of many students you get a feeling who copy-pasted-changed and who not. I would like to have a method to measure this "feeling".  Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Smells like a task for AI - definitely.

Comment: This question is not intended to save me time as a teacher! It's about fairness, e.g. when assigning grades!

Comment: @ElmoVanKiemo: Do you have an idea or an approach?

Comment: You might want to strip variable and function names from the respective [AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)s and compare them. Different students might come up with identical solutions on their own, though.

Comment: BTW, the typo in your second example is a dead giveaway of copy-paste programming. Should be `print(Add(4, 3))` :-)

Comment: can you show us the bytecode for the two scripts , I cannot see any

Comment: There are already plagiarism detection tools that you can use, I'm sure they're more sophisticated than a simple diff. I suggest you look for these rather than trying to code your own like this.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for the hint. Sometimes only the right words are missing. With 'python plagiarism detection' I quickly found several solutions ([link](https://github.com/topics/plagiarism-detection?l=python)) which could be suitable for me. Thank you. :)